# How to avoid undefined error messages in AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Sometimes, data returned from the server is not defined which results in the following appearing on my page:

```
<p id="element">undefined</p>
```

**My AJAX success function:**

```
success: function( data ) {
    $( '#element' ).text( data.message )
}
```

**PHP handler:**

```
$response = array()

// Some logic which may assign data to $response['message']

echo json_encode( $response );
die;
```

Is there a way to suppress such undefined messages?

Comment: You've to make sure response is in `json` format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what you want, you can show message only if it was provided

```
if (data.message) {
    $('#element').text(data.message)
}
```

or maybe show default message if server returns nothing (or empty string):

```
$('#element').text(data.message || 'No message.')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
success: function( data ) {

    if( data.message !== undefined )
        $( '#element' ).text( data.message )

}
```

Comment: It will never work, because `undefined` type is not equal to string 'undefined'. You probably want `if (typeof data.message != 'undefined') {}`.

Comment: @dsfq, Or maybe (data.message !== undefined) will work?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why I was confused that the type of data.message is always string...